# Do I need copy all the files in the folder "values" to the folder "values-zh-rCN" when I make an app internationalization?

Tags: android

I need to make an app internationalization, so I create the folder "values-zh-rCN", and copy all the files in the folder "values" to the folder "values-zh-rCN".
I translate the files strings.xml and array.xml in the folder "values-zh-rCN" to chinese, but I find I need not translate anything in the files styles.xml and dimens.xml in the folder "values-zh-rCN".
Can I delete the two files styles.xml and dimens.xml in the folder "values-zh-rCN"? Thanks!

Comment: yes you can delete styles.xml and dimens.xml in the folder "values-zh-rCN"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to copy `strings.xml` only. You shouldn't write strings directly in `arrays.xml` but instead reference strings contained in `strings.xml` :

```
<string-array>
    <item>@string/some_string</item>
    ...
</string-array>
```

It's easier to maintain if you decide to change your array later. You won't have to edit all of your array files (it's easy to make a mistake and put a string in the wrong item).

Comment: Thanks, but I meet trouble using your way, could you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259263/the-strings-dont-work-in-the-xml-file-located-the-folder-res-xml

Comment: But your question is not related, it's about custom XML files, not string arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Android will use the files in the default folder (values instead of values-xxx) if they are not present in a more specific folder.

For example I have an app with 6 files in values but only two in values-fr (strings and string-arrays), one in values-sw600dp and values-sw720dp (dimens), one in values-v11 (styles) and two in values-v17 (styles and dimens).

In each I only define the elements that are different from the default value and Android use those when appropriate and use the default when not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Read this [article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html), it will help you.