# The @strings don't work in the xml file located the folder res\xml\

Tags: android

I use the following code to get a nameList

I think the content of nameList will be Inbox, Sent, Outbox and Draft, it's my wish.
but in fact, the content of nameList is @string/Inbox, @string/Sent, @string/Outbox and @string/Draft.   Why? Thanks!

```
private void InitVar(){
    ArrayList nameList=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList valueList=new ArrayList<String>();
    ParXML(this, nameList, valueList);                              
}

public static void ParXML(Context context, List<String> nameList,List<String> valueList) {
    XmlResourceParser xrp = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.msgfolder);
    try {
        while (xrp.getEventType() != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (xrp.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
                String tagName = xrp.getName();
                if (tagName.equals("item")) {
                    nameList.add(xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                    valueList.add(xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "value"));
                }
            }
            xrp.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Values\strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="Inbox">Inbox</string>
    <string name="Sent">Sent</string>
    <string name="Outbox">Outbox</string>
    <string name="Draft">Draft</string>   
</resources>
```

**xml\msgfolder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MsgHandle>
   <item name="@string/Inbox" value="content://sms/inbox"></item>
   <item name="@string/Sent" value="content://sms/sent"></item>
   <item name="@string/Outbox" value="content://sms/outbox"></item>
   <item name="@string/Draft" value="content://sms/draft"></item>
</MsgHandle>
```

Comment: you cant use in your xml file @string .write inbox ,sent and ... directly in xml file

Comment: Could you tell me the details about writeng  directly in xml file ? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike other resource types, android doesn't resolve resources automatically in res/xml resources. So you have to tell it to do.

First you have to check if the parsed attribute has a resource in it:

```
int stringResId = xrp.getAttributeResourceValue(null, "name", 0);
```

if it has stringResId will be non zero. If it is zero then there is no resource identifier in the attribute value.

```
if (stringResId == 0) {
    nameList.add(xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "name")); //<-- Get attribute value as string...
} else {
    nameList.add(context.getResources().getString(stringResId)); //<-- Get string resource identified by the stringResId...
}
```

So the key here is to check with the getAttributeResourceValue which resolves the attribute value as resource is (if it is one).

Hope this helps...